# How to get unix timestamp from tomorrow nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I want to get Unix timestamp (time in seconds) from tomorrow.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDay() - 1);
d.setHours(0, 0, 0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(d/1000|0)
```

How would I fix the above?

Comment: Tomorrow is today **plus** 1, not minus 1. And use `.getDate()` not `.getDay()`.

Comment: getDay() returns the time in ms of the current day so -1 or +1 does not do anything
would getDate() change anything?

Comment: No, `getDay()` returns the day-of-the-week.

Comment: What does getDate return?

Comment: [Perhaps you should spend some time with the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: this should work as per problem description `var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
d.setHours(0, 0, 0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(d)`

Comment: BTW, `d.setMilliseconds(0)` is redundant, you can set ms as a fourth parameter when setting the hours: `d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)`. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just modified your code and it works fine

```
var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
d.setHours(0, 0, 0);
d.setMilliseconds(0);
console.log(d)
>> Sun Apr 21 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Hope this will work for you

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

Copied directly from https://javascript.info/task/get-seconds-to-tomorrow

```js
function getSecondsToTomorrow() {
  let now = new Date();

  // tomorrow date
  let tomorrow = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1);

  let diff = tomorrow - now; // difference in ms
  return Math.round(diff / 1000); // convert to seconds
}

console.log(getSecondsToTomorrow());
```

Comment: Or `let toTomorrow = new Date().setHours(24,0,0,0) - Date.now()`. ;-) If you think it's a duplicate, you should mark it as such, not just copy another answer into an answer here.

Comment: @RobG not a duplicate. That answer is from a completely different website.

Answer (score -1):

you could use a third party library like moment js which makes your life alot easier

[momentjs](https://momentjs.com/)

Comment: Saying "use library X" isn't an answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a unix timestamp and add `24*60*60*1000` (same as `86400000`) to the current time's timestamp. You can then pass that to `new Date()` like this:

- 24 = hours
- 60 = minutes
- 60 = seconds
- 1000 = converts the result to milliseconds

```js
// Current timestamp
const now = Date.now()

// Get 24 hours from now
const next = new Date(now + (24*60*60*1000))

// Create tomorrow's date
const t = new Date(next.getFullYear(), next.getMonth(), next.getDate())

// Subtract the two and divide by 1000
console.log(Math.round((t.getTime() - now) / 1000), 'seconds until tomorrow')
```

Comment: This would give incorrect results around handle leap seconds and daylight savings time.